# How to find number of data points in a given range in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to find the number of data points in my series that lie in a given range `(xMin,yMin)` to `(xMax, yMax)`. To give an example, if my series line plot looks like `(1,1)` `(2,2)` `(4,4)` `(6,7)` `(9,10)` and my range is from `(3,3)` to `(8,8)`, then 2 points satisfy the criteria I am looking for and they are => `(4,4)` `(6,7)`

(The actual problem I am trying to solve is if I have a rectangle to zoom on a series plot, then allow zooming if the rectangle of zoom at least captures N data points from the original series)

Is there an easy way to do this in d3?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straight-forward with javascript only:

```
var data = [[1,1],[2,2],[4,4],[6,7],[9,10]];

function filterData(minArr, maxArr) {
  return data.filter(function(d) {
    return d[0] >= minArr[0] &&
           d[0] <= maxArr[0] &&
           d[1] >= minArr[1] &&
           d[1] <= maxArr[1];
  });
}

console.log(filterData([3,3], [8,8]))  //[[4,4],[6,7]]
```

Comment: Very clean. Thank you.